# Eigenvalue of higher rank tensor

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I'm currently trying to calculate the eigenvalues of several matrices. However, some of my matrices are actually have more than 2 dimension (so basically, it have n x n x n x ...x n dimension). I've tried to calculate the eigenvalues by slicing the matrix, thus one matrix becomes several 2 dimensional matrices, but I don't think it is the right way to do that. Can anyone suggest in which book I could find the way to solve this problem?

Comment: Since this object isn't really a matrix, what are you expecting to learn from the "eigenvalues"?

Comment: I've typically seen the ALS used with SVD which is detailed here https://arxiv.org/abs/1410.6895

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Im actually calculating the eigenvalue of the volume operator in quantum gravity, which turns out to be a higher rank objec

Comment: @Metahominid thank you so much!